# why tex4ht adds an extra newline when using \begin{description} after \item?

Tags: tex4ht, description

Tex4ht does not seem to behave well when using `\begin{description}`. It produces output where it adds new line after each `item[x]` entry.  While in PDF it works correctly.

Here is below a MWE and screen shot of the HTML output and the PDF output. This makes using `\begin{description}` not possible in tex4ht since the HTML generated looks very bad.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}% MWE shows problem with tex4ht

\begin{document}

Example 1

\begin{description}
\item[1]  A
\item[2]  B
\item[3]  C
\item[4]  D
\item[5]  E
\end{description}

Example 2

\begin{description}
\item[]  A
\item[]  B
\item[]  C
\item[]  D
\item[]  E
\end{description}

Example 3

\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item C
\item D
\item E
\end{enumerate}    
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `make4ht bug.tex`.  Here is side-by-side, the HTML and the PDF

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that when using `\item[]` it works OK, but when putting some value inside the item, it adds new line, when it should remain on the same line like with the PDF output. i.e. `\item[1]` does not work the same way as `\item[]`.  This is example 1 above. example 2 and 3 are OK.

I am using latest update on texlive 2016

```
which tex4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tex4ht
```

Is this a known issue in tex4ht? Is there a workaround?

Comment: That's the standard behaviour in html of dd/dt. You would need some additional css to change this. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105304/displaying-dt-tag-side-by-side-instead-of-one-below-another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to style HTML description list to look in the same way as LaTeX description list. Here is my attempt:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Css{dl:after {content:"";display:table;clear:both;}}
\Css{dt{float:left;min-width:3em;clear:left;}}
\Css{dd{float:left;}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

The `dt` and `dd` elements hold the description label and text. We use some simple CSS to put them on the same line. Note that it doesn't work in every instance:

[image]

So multi-line descriptions still end on new lines. I don't know how to fix that.